# How to avoid Mercurial repo corruption when sharing a repository between Windows/Mac?

Tags: macos, mercurial, parallels

I have several projects which are shared between Windows and Mac.  The dev machine is a Mac running Parallels: the files are stored on the Mac side, and the source is shared to the Windows side.  This is very convenient, as I can switch back and forth between Windows and Mac tools rapidly without having to sync files.

Recently I switched from Subversion to Mercurial, and now I'm having problems with the Mercurial repository becoming corrupt if I use the Windows tools to add/update, etc.  I have to be very careful about which operations on the Windows side are safe (mainly the read-only stuff) and of course I forget rather regularly.

Does anybody know why the corruption occurs?  I thought Mercurial repositories were platform-agnostic.   Any ideas how to prevent it without removing the Windows tools entirely?

Comment: AFAIK it's a problem with parallels http://mercurial.selenic.com/bts/issue2031

Comment: Thanks... I'm not sure why that would be an issue, but Ry4an suggested I create a pre-commit hook on Windows that will always fail, to prevent committing from Windows.   That will solve my forgetfulness at least :)

Comment: Why not just do "the right thing" and clone on the windows machine from the mac repo - then just `hg pull -u` every time you go over to windows and you won't run the risk of any kind of corruption (and you're also free to make changes and just push them back to the mac with `hg push`)

Comment: Because the main value of the shared code is in being able to move back and forth without even committing the changes.  This is very common in a case where (for example) we modify a function which is shared by Mac and Windows, then compile and smoke test both platforms.  I don't want to commit the change until both work, and so pushing them back and forth would make for a messy change history.   Also, there are many uncontrolled files that are shared as well, so they would have to be sync'ed separately.

Comment: Man, I got the same problem as you. I'm editing my source files with XCode and commiting on Parallels with Mercurial. Why is Mercurial on windows under Parallels unable to commit safely?

Comment: I believe the basic issue is that the underlying binary representation is not compatible at the file level.  While it's true that Mercurial is cross-platform, that applies to syncing files via the network protocol -- it does NOT mean that you can copy the files byte-for-byte from Windows to Mac and expect the repository to remain uncorrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are both the windows side and the OSX side using the same version of mercurial.  Mercurial has great backwards compatibility at the network and file level in that any version can push/pull/commit to any previous version's repositories, but it's not forward-compatible, so if your windows side is using mercurial 1.0 and your OSX side is at 1.5 then windows shouldn't be committing to a clone created by the OSX side.

In general mercurial was built for a clone-per-user-per-system and having conflicting actions mediated through push and pull.  Shared repos accessed by multiple clients for local-only actions like commit isn't the recommended use case.

Editing on both systems is fine, but commit from OSX only.  On the windows side you could enforce that by putting something like this in your %USER_PROFILE%\Mercurial.ini file:

```
[hooks]
pre-commit = c:\doesnotexist.exe
```

That should be enough for the hook to fail, which will stop the commit from going through.

Comment: I like your pre-commit idea!

Both clients are hg 1.5.1, so I don't think I'll get relief from that.   But just being able to prevent commits on Windows would end my worst suffering, so I'll try the pre-commit hook.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Mind picking the answer then?